# ArgumentNullException for address when sending email using NetCore.MailKit

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, mailkit

I am using **NetCore.MailKit** NuGet package to help me send an email which contains a link to confirm their email when the user registers. I have followed the steps on their [Github page](https://github.com/myloveCc/NETCore.MailKit) but, I am getting an `ArgumentNullException` for the address, even though I have set the sending address.

The **error**:

```
ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'address')
    MimeKit.MailboxAddress..ctor(Encoding encoding, string name, string address)
```

The above error occurs when is send the email in my controller using IEmailService:

```
_EmailService.Send("usersemail@gmail.com", "subject", "message body");
```

This is my `appsettings.json` configuration:

```
  "EmailConfiguration": {
    "Server": "smtp.gmail.com",
    "Port": 587,
    "SenderName": "name",
    "SenderEmail": "mygmail@gmail.com",
    "SenderPassword": "My gmail password"
  }
```

This is my setup in `startup.cs`

```
    services.AddMailKit(optionBuilder =>
    {
        optionBuilder.UseMailKit(new MailKitOptions()
        {
            //get options from sercets.json
            Server = Configuration["Server"],
            Port = Convert.ToInt32(Configuration["Port"]),
            SenderName = Configuration["SenderName"],
            SenderEmail = Configuration["SenderEmail"],
            Account = Configuration["SenderEmail"],
            Password = Configuration["SenderPassword"],
            Security = true
        });
    });
```

Below is the code for EmailService:

```
    public void Send(string mailTo, string subject, string message, bool isHtml = false)
    {
        SendEmail(mailTo, null, null, subject, message, Encoding.UTF8, isHtml);
    }

    private void SendEmail(string mailTo, string mailCc, string mailBcc, string subject, string message, Encoding encoding, bool isHtml)
    {
        var _to = new string[0];
        var _cc = new string[0];
        var _bcc = new string[0];
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(mailTo))
            _to = mailTo.Split(',').Select(x => x.Trim()).ToArray();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(mailCc))
            _cc = mailCc.Split(',').Select(x => x.Trim()).ToArray();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(mailBcc))
            _bcc = mailBcc.Split(',').Select(x => x.Trim()).ToArray();

        Check.Argument.IsNotEmpty(_to, nameof(mailTo));
        Check.Argument.IsNotEmpty(message, nameof(message));

        var mimeMessage = new MimeMessage();

        //add mail from
        mimeMessage.From.Add(new MailboxAddress(_MailKitProvider.Options.SenderName, _MailKitProvider.Options.SenderEmail));

        //add mail to 
        foreach (var to in _to)
        {
            mimeMessage.To.Add(MailboxAddress.Parse(to));
        }

        //add mail cc
        foreach (var cc in _cc)
        {
            mimeMessage.Cc.Add(MailboxAddress.Parse(cc));
        }

        //add mail bcc 
        foreach (var bcc in _bcc)
        {
            mimeMessage.Bcc.Add(MailboxAddress.Parse(bcc));
        }

        //add subject
        mimeMessage.Subject = subject;

        //add email body
        TextPart body = null;

        if (isHtml)
        {

            body = new TextPart(TextFormat.Html);
        }
        else
        {
            body = new TextPart(TextFormat.Text);
        }
        //set email encoding
        body.SetText(encoding, message);

        //set email body
        mimeMessage.Body = body;

        using (var client = _MailKitProvider.SmtpClient)
        {
            client.Send(mimeMessage);
        }
    }
```

As you can see I have set everything, am I missing something here? why is address null at `MimeKit.MailboxAddress()`?

Comment: Posting the code of the `EmailService` would be helpful

Comment: I have updated the question with EmailService, the rest can be found at the link I provided @JSteward

Comment: which line does the exception get thrown on in your code?

Comment: _EmailService.Send("usersemail@gmail.com", "subject", "message body"); @jstedfast

Comment: No, it gets thrown inside the EmailService.SendEmail() method - but where?

Comment: When MailBoxAddress instance is created, it says the address is null @jstedfast

Comment: Is it this line? `mimeMessage.From.Add(new MailboxAddress(_MailKitProvider.Options.SenderName, _MailKitProvider.Options.SenderEmail));`

Comment: Yes that is the line @jstedfast

Comment: did  you solved it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be not loading your configuration settings correctly. I suspect the failing line in your code is

```
//add mail from
mimeMessage.From.Add(new MailboxAddress(_MailKitProvider.Options.SenderName, _MailKitProvider.Options.SenderEmail));
```

The Options are all null, which causes the exception.

When you load the settings from a configuration file you need to prepend the section name to the variables. E.G.

```
services.AddMailKit(optionBuilder =>
{
    optionBuilder.UseMailKit(new MailKitOptions()
    {
        //get options from sercets.json
        Server = Configuration["EmailConfiguration:Server"],
        Port = Convert.ToInt32(Configuration["EmailConfiguration:Port"]),
        SenderName = Configuration["EmailConfiguration:SenderName"],
        SenderEmail = Configuration["EmailConfiguration:SenderEmail"],
        Account = Configuration["EmailConfiguration:SenderEmail"],
        Password = Configuration["EmailConfiguration:SenderPassword"],
        Security = true
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the exception is being thrown on the following line:

```
mimeMessage.From.Add(new MailboxAddress(_MailKitProvider.Options.SenderName, _MailKitProvider.Options.SenderEmail));
```

This means that `_MailKitProvider.Options.SenderEmail` is `null`.

I know you expect these values to be loaded correctly from your appsettings.json file, but seemingly, they are not being loaded for some reason.